# Microsoft Excel: How to match two column and count the duplicate?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Please see this image first: [image: excel sheet]

Range 1:

| Reference No | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/123ABC | Approved |
| 2022/123ABC | Approved |
| 2022/123ABC | Pending |
| 2022/DEF345 | Approved |
| 2022/DEF345 | Pending |

Range 2:

| Reference No | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/123ABC | 500 |
| 2022/DEF345 | 600 |

Calculation Area:

| Reference No | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/123ABC | 500 |
|  | 3 |
|  | 497 |

and

| Reference No | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/123ABC | 500 |
| Approved | 2 |
|  | 498 |

Here I'm matching with range 1 and range 2 and count the duplicate and make a calculation. But I can only match the Reference No only. How can I match the Reference No and Status also.

Please see the image, in D4 cell I will put the reference no, if match found It will count. And If I put the status in D5 cell, it will count only matching the reference no and status.

I have tried with this

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D5),COUNTIF(A:A,D4),COUNTIFS(A:A,D4 ,(B:B,D5)))
```

but it shows error two many argumants entered.

Comment: Since this is not a free code-writing service, in accordance with the forum guidelines, please **edit** your question to show what you have tried.

Comment: Instead of COUNTIF COUNTIFS?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D6),COUNTIF(A:A,D5),COUNTIFS(A:A,D5,B:B,D6))
```